# Fastify with TypeScript, How to validate and type a routes request?

Tags: typescript, fastify

My basic server, imports and registers the route `join` and adds the TypeProvider to fastify.

```
import Fastify from "fastify";
import { join } from "./routes/onboarding/join";
import { JsonSchemaToTsProvider } from "@fastify/type-provider-json-schema-to-ts";

const fastify = Fastify({
  logger: true,
}).withTypeProvider<JsonSchemaToTsProvider>();

fastify.register(join);

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await fastify.listen({ port: 3000 });
  } catch (err) {
    fastify.log.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

start();
```

join route...

```
import {
  FastifyInstance,
  FastifyReply,
  FastifyRequest,
} from "fastify";

export async function join(fastify: FastifyInstance, _options: Object) {
  fastify.post(
    "/animals",
    {
      schema: {
        body: {
          type: "object",
          required: ["animal"],
          properties: {
            animal: { type: "string" },
          },
        },
      } as const,
    },
    async (request: FastifyRequest, _reply: FastifyReply) => {
      const { animal } = request.body;  <=== errors here on animal
      return animal;
    }
  );
}
```

The error I get with a red squiggle on `const { animal }`

```
Property 'animal' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)
```

The docs are [here](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Type-Providers/) but I guess they are not that clear

Answer (score 4):

The `@fastify/type-provider-json-schema-to-ts` Type Provider exports a plugin type `FastifyPluginAsyncJsonSchemaToTs` that helps TypeScript determine types from the schema definition.

In your example, declare `join` as that type and remove the explicit parameter types from the plugin function and the handler:

```
import { FastifyPluginAsyncJsonSchemaToTs } from "@fastify/type-provider-json-schema-to-ts";

export const join: FastifyPluginAsyncJsonSchemaToTs = async function (
  fastify,
  _options
) {
  fastify.post(
    "/animals",
    {
      schema: {
        body: {
          type: "object",
          required: ["animal"],
          properties: {
            animal: { type: "string" },
          },
        },
      } as const,
    },
    async (request, _reply) => {
      const { animal } = request.body; // animal is string
      return animal;
    }
  );
};
```

Now, `animal` has type `string`.